# What is a good way to minify JS & CSS when uploading a NodeJS app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, minify

I am used to using Rails, and I really enjoy the asset pipeline. The ease that CSS & JS just is minified and bundled automatically when you upload your app.

What is the best way to have something similar in NodeJS, or should the deployment process be a bit different from what I am used to in Rails?

Comment: you could use a [gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) as a task runner that you run to take care of all the minification/preprocessing you want to do.

For minifying js you can use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

For minifying css you can use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

Answer (score 2):

### Simple regex CSS minifier/compressor

PS: I hate to use different frameworks and libraries where they are not needed.
So, I want propose my easiest way that allows to minify and simplify CSS.

### Features

- Remove all comments
- Remove all empty declarations
- Remove all whitespaces that are unnecessary 
  (including around the meta characters, such as **{ } ( ) : ; > ~ +** etc.)
- Remove the last "**;**" in a rule declaration
- Remove leading zero in float value. For example: **0.5** > **.5**
- Convert **HEX color** to short value when it's possible. For example: **#CCCCCC** > **#CCC**
- Remove for all zero values units (such as %,px,pt,pc,rem,em,ex,cm,mm,in) that are unnecessary (excluding CSS keyframes). For example: **border: 1px 0px** > **border:1px 0**

### The code

```
function minifyCSS (css) {
    return String(css)
        .replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g, ' ') // Comments
        .replace(/\s+/g, ' ') // Extra spaces
        .replace(/([\(\)\{\}\:\;\,]) /g, '$1') // Extra spaces
        .replace(/ \{/g, '{') // Extra spaces
        .replace(/\;\}/g, '}') // Last semicolon
        .replace(/ ([+~>]) /g, '$1') // Extra spaces
        .replace(/([^{][,: \(\)]0)(%|px|pt|pc|rem|em|ex|cm|mm|in)([, };\(\)])/g, '$1$3') // Units for zero values
        .replace(/([: ,=\-\(])0\.(\d)/g, '$1.$2') // Lead zero for float values
        .replace(/([^\}]*\{\s*?\})/g, '') // Empty rules
        .replace(/([,: \(])#([0-9a-f]{6})/gi, function(m, pfx, clr) { // HEX code reducing
            if (clr[0] == clr[1] && clr[2] == clr[3] && clr[4] == clr[5]) return pfx + '#' + clr[0] + clr[2] + clr[4];
            return pfx + '#' + clr;
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The deployment process will be different but there are lots of minifiers out there for javascript. I recommend using connect, then you can use this handy guy:

https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager

Comment: Pretty nifty tool but I have always thought that using your application server to serve up files is "bad" practice.  Let tried and true static servers such as `nginx` and `apache` do all the heavy lifting, they have many useful features as well. This would apply to any application in any language but in a single threaded enviroment this would even be more important.

Comment: Usually you would just use a CDN in front of it, and then it wouldn't be so much of an issue.